# Remove Employer/Job Title Fields and Reorder Fields

Tags: contacts

How do I remove the "employer" "job title" "nickname" fields in the Individual contact summary? Is there a way to reorganize the information on this screen (e.g., demographics should go first)?

I'm currently running the most recent version of CiviCRM 4.6.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the order of the panels under Display Preferences here: civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1

The order of your custom data sets will be based on the order of your Custom Data here: civicrm/admin/custom/group?reset=1

Under display preferences you can also hide some fields, but not the ones you're after. We never customize our installations to remove those types of fields. Unless you have the skills in house for those types of customizations, you may end up relying on a developer for each upgrade to hide them every time. Most find that an unnecessary expense and just ignore them.

Heather.

Comment: Thanks, Heather! I'm surprised that employer information would appear right underneath the contact name, rather than the demographics. I appreciate you taking the time to provide me a response!

Comment: Ignoring was taking place before and the question expresses the desire to move beyond it. The answer is therefore less helpful. May be some hints how to do this yourself without expensive developers?

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to be a developer and your are asked to do this you can take the following route.

- Create a new extension.
- Identify the class that generates the unwanted field. For example, the employer field is created by `CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary`.
- Add a template in your extension with the same name (and directory) as the template that belongs to this class, with only one difference. Add `extra` before the `.tpl`. So for `CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary` the template is `\templates\CRM\Contact\Page\View\Summary.extra.tpl`. The contents of this template wil be appended to the regular template.
- Add some javascript code that hides the field.

Example:

```
 {literal}
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('.crm-contact-current_employer').parent().hide();
 </script>
 {/literal}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Contact Layout Editor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor) extension, first released in 2018, allows you to do quite a bit of hiding and rearranging on the Contact Summary screen.

Comment: The Contact Layout Editor doesn't allow to edit the layout of the screen for editing a contact, it only allows to edit the Contact Summary screen, as Noah says.